# Function to calculate the total of the sequence

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the sum of this sequence in R.

The sequence will have two Inputs (1 and 11) in the below case,

```
1 + (1 * 2/3 ) + (1 * 2/3 * 4/5) + ( 1 * 2/3 * 4/5 * 6/7) + ....................(1 *......10/11)
```

I think, defining my own is the way to go here.

Comment: Does this sequence have any mathematical name?

Comment: Is this term `(1 * 2/3)` missing?

Comment: @Jimbou Yes Sorry, just updated the question. Thanks

Comment: @amrrs No, I am afraid - It doesn't follow an AP or GP Series to my knowledge.

Comment: So the increment is always one right?

Comment: @amrrs Yes, its always one.

Comment: is this correct? `a <- seq(1, 11, 2);
sum(c(1,cumprod((a-1)[-1]))/cumprod(a))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try just using old-fashioned loops here:

```
sum <- 0
num_terms <- 6
for (i in 1:num_terms) {
    y <- 1
    if (i > 1) {
        for (j in 1:(i-1)) {
            y <- y * (j*2 / (j*2 + 1))
        }
    }
    sum <- sum + y
}
```

You can set `num_terms` to any value you want, from `1` to a higher value.  In this case, I use `6` terms because this is the requested number of terms in your question.

Someone will probably come along and reduce the entire code snippet above to one line, but in my mind an explicit loop is justified here.

Here is a link to a demo which prints out the values being used in each of the terms, for verification purposes:

## Demo

Comment: Great. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

My approach:

```
# input
start <- 1
n <- 5 # number of terms

end <- start + n*2

result <- start
to_add <- start

for (i in (start + 1):(end-1)) {
  to_add <- to_add * (i / (i + 1))
  result <- result + to_add
}
```

which gives:

```
> result
[1] 4.039755
```

Comment: This may not give the results you intend.  For example, if `start=1` and `end=2`, the bounds of your for loop would be `for (i in 2:1)`.

Comment: Hmm true. I've modified the code so that the input is the starting number and the number of terms following

Answer (score 1):

Another base R alternative using `cumprod` to generate the inner terms is

```
sum(cumprod(c(1, seq(2, 10, 2)) / c(1, seq(3, 11, 2))))
[1] 3.4329
```

Here, `c(1, seq(2, 10, 2)) / c(1, seq(3, 11, 2))` generates the sequence 1, 2/3, 4/5, 6/7, 8/9, 10/11 and `cumprod` takes the cumulative product. This result is summed with `sum`. The returned result is identical to the one in the accepted answer.

Comment: This is quite similar to identical to my comment `a <- seq(1, 11, 2);
sum(c(1,cumprod((a-1)[-1]))/cumprod(a))`

Comment: @Jimbou Yes. I saw that comment after I worked out this answer and posted it. If you want to add it to your answer, let me know and I'll delete it.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
library(tidyverse)
Result <- tibble(a=seq(1, 11, 2)) %>%
  mutate(b=lag(a, default = 0)+1) %>% 
  mutate(Prod=cumprod(b)/cumprod(a)) %>%  
  mutate(Sum=cumsum(Prod)) 
Result 
  # A tibble: 6 x 4
      a     b      Prod      Sum
  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1     1 1.0000000 1.000000
2     3     2 0.6666667 1.666667
3     5     4 0.5333333 2.200000
4     7     6 0.4571429 2.657143
5     9     8 0.4063492 3.063492
6    11    10 0.3694084 3.432900

# and some graphical analysis
Result %>% 
  ggplot(aes(as.factor(a), Prod, group=1)) + 
    geom_col(aes(as.factor(a), Sum), alpha=0.4)+ 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_line()
```

[image]